# search for null cells in column of mysql database and display on the datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

My application requires to search the incompleted projects in our task management software. And for that i am trying to implement a way i could read our MySQL database for incomplete projects and display them on the screen. The project will be incomplete if the particular cell is a "null value". The project is completed when the cell says "Completed". I am trying to search for all null values in a row and display them on to the `DataGridView` with visual basic C#. 
The code i tried is the following, unfortunately it didn't work:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(dt);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("BackSheetAssembled LIKE '%{0}%'", DBNull.Value );
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
}
```

I tried the same method with substituting `DBNull.Value` with a text box and it works fine and search the database for those texts, but it doesn't work for a `Null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DV.RowFilter = "Isnull(BackSheetAssembled,'') = ''";
```

Comment: You can remove the string.Format.

Comment: works like a charm. If i may ask, what is happening in that statement?

Comment: Ammar - you want "is null"

Comment: In this way we are filtering using ISNULL function. Isnull function returns empty string if the cells value is null and then comparing with empty string gives us result

Comment: I see.. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

DV.RowFilter = "BackSheetAssembled is null";

Example:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 123, "Name1" });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 234, "Name2"});
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, "Name3" });

var view = new DataView(table);
view.RowFilter = "Id is null";

for (int i = 0; i < view.Count; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(view[i][1].ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Outputs: Name3

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)